# Is there a guide to the incompatible changes in python's requests module version 1.0?

Tags: python, python-requests

The popular Python requests module went to 1.0 last year and made a number of backwards-incompatible API changes. I'm sure they're great, but I'm trying to port some existing code over to the latest version 1.1 and I can't figure out what happened to the functionality I was relying on.

Specifically, the `return_response` keyword argument to `requests.get()` is no longer valid and `requests.defaults` no longer exists. It's not clear if there is any way to set `max_retries` anymore. Heck, I can't even find the blog post where Requests 1.0 was announced! The link that was posted on Hacker News is 404:
http://kennethreitz.org/announcing-requests-v100.html

So I'm either looking for a guide to the incompatible differences between Requests 1.0 and the previous version (I think 14.2) or at least some assistance with the issues described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question, a [migration guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api.html#migrating-to-1-x) has been added to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions I've found to my immediate porting problems:

```
# instead of
requests.get(..., return_response=false)
# use:
requests.Request(...).prepare()

# instead of
request.full_url
# use a requests.PreparedRequest and
request.url

# for an unsent request, instead of
request.send()
# use
s = requests.Session()
s.send(request)

# instead of
requests.defaults.defaults['max_retries'] = val
# use
requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = val
```